# Mock a dependency of a React component using Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a react component (CreateForm). The React component depends on a module (Store). The CreateForm has a Cancel button. On clicking the cancel button, the handleCancel function of the Store module should be called.

I wrote a test unsuccessfully using Jest:

```
test.only('should handle cancel button click', () => {
    jest.mock('../../src/store');
    const store = require('../../src/store');
    const wrapper = shallow(<CreateForm />);
    const cancelButton = wrapper.find('button').at(1);
    cancelButton.simulate('click');
    expect(store.default.handleCancel).toBeCalled();
});
```

The test failed. The mock function did not get called and the test failed. Does the react component not get this version of the mock? If so, how do I fix the test? Thanks.

My CreateForm component looks something like the below:

```
import Store from './store';

render() {
   return (
     <Panel>
       <FormControls />
       <button onClick={Store.create}>Create</button>
       <button onClick={Store.handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
    </Panel>
  );
}
```

A second improvised test that works for me is shown below.

```
test.only('should handle cancel button click', () => {
  const store = require('../../src/store').default;
  const cancel = store.handleCancel;
  store.handleCancel = jest.fn();

  const wrapper = shallow(<CreateForm />);
  const cancelButton = wrapper.find('button').at(1);
  cancelButton.simulate('click');
  expect(store.handleCancel).toBeCalled();

  store.handleCancel = cancel;
});
```

The above test works. I am manually mocking the function, doing the test and restoring the function back to its original after the test. Is there a better way or Jest way of writing the above test? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I have managed to spy on imported functions using Jest.

Import everything that is imported in the file you're testing.

Mock it in the `beforeEach`, you can use more complex mocking if you need to return values or whatever.

In the `afterEach` call `jest.clearAllMocks()` to reset all the functions to normal to stop any mocking falling through to other tests.

Putting it all together it looks something like this.

```
import shallow from 'enzyme'
import * as Store from './Store' // This should be the actual path from the test file to the import

describe('mocking', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(Store, 'handleCancel')
    jest.spyOn(Store, 'create')
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  })

  test.only('should handle cancel button click', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<CreateForm />);
    const cancelButton = wrapper.find('button').at(1);
    cancelButton.simulate('click');
    expect(Store.handleCancel).toBeCalled();
  })
})
```

Also, in case you need to mock a default import you can do so like this. `jest.spyOn(Store, 'default')`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to tell jest how to mock the store module, in your case it is just `undefined`.

```
const store = require('../../src/store');
jest.mock('../../src/store', () =>({
 handleCancel: jest.fn()
}));

test.only('should handle cancel button click', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<CreateForm />);
    const cancelButton = wrapper.find('button').at(1);
    cancelButton.simulate('click');
    expect(store.default.handleCancel).toBeCalled();//I'm not sure about the default here
});
```

With this solution you tell jest to mock the store with an object that has the `handleCancel` function which is a jest spy. On this spy you can then test that it was called.

Comment: This does not work for me. CreateForm uses the Store module. The Store module still seems to work with the original object and not the mock. Thanks.